# equivalent to curl --data in go http request payload

Tags: go

For the purpose of setting a K/V in a NoSQL storage, I need to create an equivalent to the following **curl** command in go:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data '[...]' http://localhost:8000/test/testrow/test:testcolumn
```

I am trying to use something in the lines of the following code for that purpose, although I am unable to find how to set the binary data  *[]byte(value)* as a POST payload.

```
func setColumn(table string, key string, col string, value string) {

url := "http://localhost:8123/" + table + "/" + key + "/" + col
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, nil)
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")

data = []byte(value)

client := &http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
fmt.Println(string(body))
```

}

So, how to map the data payload within the POST request ? Any indicators are welcome.

Comment: Which NoSQL storage ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to post any data  you should  pass the value instead of **nil** 
in the    [Newrequest](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest) method.

This should  work

```
func setColumn(table string, key string, col string, value string) {

    url := "http://localhost:8123/" + table + "/" + key + "/" + col
    **data := bytes.NewReader([]byte(value))**
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, **data**)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

Most of the NoSQL Servers has GO API use them instad of creating your own HTTP request.

Comment: this return `non-name * (*data) on left side of :=`
`syntax error: unexpected := at end of statement` error

Comment: @mapmalith remove **s. they are for emphasizing